Stop/Prevent body From Scrolling To Top On dialog.showModal()
I have a div, with a list of divs, that exceeds the height of the browser window.
Each div is an item of interest, with a onClick event.
Exposing the bad behavior of dialog.showModal():
Scroll To Bottom Of List Causing Top Of Page To Scroll Out Of Sight.
User clicks on a DIV, in the list, and an event is triggered that calls for a dialog to be opened with showModal()
oDlg.showModal() ;
The Page Is Scrolled Back To The Top Causing The div that was clicked on to now scroll out of view below the bottom of the browser window, then the dialog is made visible.
All I Want To Do Is Stop The Body From Scrolling.
I have seen many suggestions that do not work dating back from 2012.
I am hoping since it is now middle of 2024; there is an actual solution to this design flaw of showModal().
Why can the dialog not just open exactly over where the body is currently positioned.
I have tried scrolling the page after the dialog is opened; but then the dialog is scrolled off  the top of the page.
I have seen suggestions like <a href="javascript(void), bootstrap, jquery, body{position:absolute;}.
I tried the position of body; did not change the behavior of showModal.
I am using Pure HTML, Javascript and CSS.
I believe that this behavior, of showModal, is a defect!

Instead of explaining your code, show it! Notice, that <dialog> is a quite regular HTML element, and can be positioned as any other element.

Just confirming that I too ran into this issue in 2024

@Teemu
A dialog element can not be positioned any where on the page!
It takes no top, left, right or bottom properties.

No?. Your issue is, that you've somehow positioned your dialog. Removing all the positioning attributes from the dialog element will fix your issue. By default, dialog has fixed position centered to the viewport, and no scrolling will take place when the element is shown. Just keep searching the used CSS to find and remove all the positioning properties concerning the dialog.

In my case, the solution was to remove position: relative; from the styling of the modal/dialog element.
When this was removed, the page no longer scrolled to the top.
Other CSS I have applied to the dialog element in case it makes a difference:
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: fit-content;
  max-height: 90vh;
  width: 500px;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;


Man this made me so excited... I raced over to my editor... I open the css file, I  deleted posotion: relative; from the dialog class.
Pushed it into production and tested. The the page is still scrolled to the top before the dialog opens.
So for me this did not work.
I inspected the element and now Position reports to be "Fixed".

Can you change it from fixed to just not specifying a position? Or specify initial or unset? Edit – actually, the computed property of the element in my case also reports fixed, yet it doesn't cause the page scroll.

One other thing you might want to try is adding overscroll-behavior: contain; to the dialog CSS. I've edited my answer to add other relevant CSS I have applied to the dialog.

I did not specify a position at all. The DOM did that. I simply check the Developer Tool in chrome to see what the Computed CSS was on the element.
I will try each one of these CSS settings separate and see if any make a difference individually. I have never used Flex before.
I appreciate your help Adam Reis.

No problem, it's an annoying issue for sure. Let me know how you go. I can confirm that in my case the element/inspector also reports fixed position if I don't specify anything. So maybe it's a combination of several CSS properties.
